# What's wrong with RDP Windows 10 client?

Tags: networking, dns, remote-desktop

Connecting to Windows Server 2012 via Windows 10 Enterprise.

When I connect using .rdp it will connect very slow when I enter a specified domain name (which has been added in our internal netwerk).
However, when I specify the (internal) IP adress of the machine, it will connect instantly. Please read we have a site-to-site VPN to connect the the server.

DNS does not appear to be the problem, as pinging the domain will result in instant reply. What am I missing?

Tried so far:

- nslookup,
- flushdns
- **other pc (please note: on another fresh installed laptop it works instantly.)**

Comment: Perhaps mstsc is not leveraging the DNS cache and thus doing a lookup every time which would account for the slow response vs. fast response. Try `ipconfig /flushdns` and try that ping/rdp again noting any differences.

Comment: flushdns did not solve anything. However, thanks for your note.

Comment: Does nslookup [Hostname] return the same internal IP or some other IP(perhaps its external)?

Comment: @Linef4ult the hostname will show the exact address it's supposed to be.

Comment: Please note on a fresh installed laptop, it works like a charm. What could be corrupting my pc?

Comment: @Rob - Bloatware

Comment: @Rob - This is meant for Win Server 2008, but you could try it anyways. Open the .RDP file in Notepad and add this line: enablecredsspsupport:i:0